# Sorting object entries in a list of objects JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how to sort the objects inside a list of objects. It looks like this:

```
  {
    ITEMS: {
        dress: {color: "red", size: "S"}
        boots: {color: "black", size: "36"}
        bag: {color: "cream", size: "one"}
      }
    ITEMS_2: {
        dress: {color: "red", size: "S"}
        boots: {color: "black", size: "36"}
        bag: {color: "cream", size: "one"}
      }
   }
```

How would I sort alphabetically dress, boots, bag ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since this is an object, there is no way to 'sort' it. They're indexed by their keys, not in any particular order. What are you trying to do that requires them to be sorted? This may be a slight XY problem.

Comment: If you need ordered list, use arrays instead.... `ITEMS: [{type: "dress", color: "red", size: "S"}, {...}, {...}]`

Comment: @matthew-e-brown - Object properties have order now. But it's still usually a bad idea to make use of that order. :-)

Comment: I would like to display them in a list but alphabetically ordered.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `sort alphabetically dress, boots, bag`? Can you share a sample output that you are expecting after the sort?

Comment: When rendered would love to have them as:
<ul> 
    <li>bag</li>
    <li>boots</li>
    <li>dress</li>
</ul>

Comment: @AJH - I suggest using an array of `{name: "dress", color: "red", "size" "S"}` and similar objects (or if `color` and `size` really need to be on their own, `{name: "dress", options: {color: "red", "size" "S"}}`).

Comment: Thanks. Will use that approach instead! ^^